# Alias settings are not Persisted in Netbeans Terminal

Tags: netbeans, terminal, cygwin, alias

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1 (mainly `PHP` and stuff) which is latest stable release at the moment.
But the issue I'm facing existed even before this version.

The problem is, Whenever I set the `alias` for a program, in the Netbeans terminal

(`Window->Output->Terminal`) and close the terminal, all the set alias are gone.

The same happens in `Cygwin`.

This is very frustrating.
Is this a bug and I have to live with it or I have to make some tweaks?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, perhaps it's not Netbeans' fault.

The problem (I'm not sure if it is really) is with Cygwin, when I do `alias "foo=bar"` it
forgets everything when I close the Cygwin terminal or the Terminal in Netbeans.

Eventually, I had to add `alias "foo=bar"` and every other necessary alias in the /home/.bashrc file.

And the Netbeans Terminal won't know anything about the aliases i have set until I manually run

`. ~/.bashrc`

Which raises another question, how can I make Netbeans Terminal load `.bashrc` automatically whenever I launch the Terminal?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Windows (since you're using Cygwin), go to Cygwin

```
cd               # go to homedirectory
notepad .bashrc  # add line "alias foo=bar" in notepad window"
exit
```

`Window->Output->Terminal` in Netbeans launches `sh` not `bash`. So when you go there, type "bash" and you'll have access to all your alias that you could access on Cygwin.

I've Netbeans 7.3.1 and Cygwin 1.7.22 and it's working fine for me.

Comment: Exactly! but the question remains pretty much the same, why `sh` forgets/discards my alias settings?
What *.rc file the sh in nesteans reads?

please have a look at the my answer below, thx